# Spring data jpa repository findBy returning null even if data present in DB

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring data JPA, facing issue as result is always coming NULL even if record present into DB.

I tried debugging spring code and checked whether statement created correctly or not. Statement is created correctly and parameter is also populated correctly.

Configuration: -
Spring-boot = 2.0.5.RELEASE

Oracle DB = Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit

**POM**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Entity class:**

```
@Entity()
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_Sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_Sequence", sequenceName = "USER_SEQ")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String userName;
    
    private String password;
    //getter & setter
```

**Repository class**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends 
org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository<User, Long>{

    User findByUserName(String userName);
    
    User save(User user);
}
```

**Service class**

```
@Service("loginService")
public class LoginService implements ILoginService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Override
    public boolean isValidUser(String userName, String password) {
        User user = userRepository.findByUserName(userName);
        if(user != null && user.getUserName().equals(userName) && user.equals(password)){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Debug Screenshot : -
[Debug Screenshot parameter value is "admin" and SQL formed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWzF9.jpg)

SQL Formed : -

```
select user0_."id" as id1_2_, user0_."password" as password2_2_, user0_."user_name" as user_name3_2_ from "user" user0_ where user0_."user_name"=?
```

If I run same query in DB, result is : -
[Result Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QT9p.jpg)

Comment: Code is finding User by userName, Not by Id.

Comment: I know that it might sound obvious, but have you checked application.yml/properties if the datasource is configured properly? Note: you can use `boolean existsByUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password)` instead - it will be a little bit faster than fetching whole user entity.

Comment: Sorry I read the question wrong. Try chaing the annotation to `@Column(name = "user_name", unique=true)` to your `userName` entity

Comment: are you sure findByUserName() is returning null in this case? or isValidUser() is returning just false?

Comment: findByUserName() function is returning null.

Comment: Data source and everything is working fine. As i am able to get data from another table using findById().

Comment: Repository code changes should be : List<User> findByUsername(String username); . And ensure @Column(name = "user_name", unique=true) this added as per @locus2k comments Ref: https://www.concretepage.com/spring-5/spring-data-crudrepository-example

Comment: Nice point @Senthil, I was thinking mentioning UNIQUE=true will never have duplicate name records in DB. But I tried "locus2k" & your changes to make return type as List<User>, but still no luck.

Comment: @sourabhteke Did u find a solution for this? Facing the same issue. With the same database and spring version.

Comment: @sourabhteke I am facing the same issue, But my scenario is slightly different. My data and DDL is migrated from the production database and when I try to fetch data it returns null. When I bring/get data from other tables It returns perfectly fine so database connection is working.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using your column name as your field names it needs to know what to map to in your entity.

Change your field to either be `user_name` or change:

```
@Column(unique=true)
private String userName;
```

to

```
@Column(name="user_name", unique=true)
private String userName;
```

thus it will be able to know what column it references;

https://www.concretepage.com/spring-5/spring-data-crudrepository-example

Comment: I tried doing your suggested changes. But No luck. Same result. But i think, this is not mandatory as query formed by Hibernate(mentioned in main post) is picking correct column name and table is also created using Hibernate Auto DDL. I tried manually running query into DB, which got printed by hibernate logging and gives result properly screenshot attached in main post.

Comment: Spring may require the annotation (not sure) but also might suggest making sure you have the latest spring-jpa libraries. There might be a bug i the one you're using? the latest version is `2.1.1.RELEASE`

Answer (score 0):

use findByNameEqualsAndStatus in Repository

Answer (score 0):

Below are things that work for me. I am using Oracle 19C with org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect.

```
grant all on <schema>.<table> to <user>;
grant all on <schema>.<sequence> to <user>;
```